# Connect to Virtualbox VM filesystem (without using shared folders)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu server-based VM running on virtualbox in headless mode.

I want to expose the *virtual machine's file system*, so the host can access it.

For example, I want to expose the /app directory in the VM file system, so that Atom or Visual Studio running on the host can edit it.

**I do not want to use shared folders to accomplish this.**  I don't want the added complexity of syncronizing both the VM, and the shared folders between two machines.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SFTPnetdrive](http://sftpnetdrive.com)

It will mount your linux filesystem in your windows. So that all your applications can access the file in linux system